# C# - processor architecture mismatch

Tags: c#, webkit

Here is the error which occurs when I added the library webKitBrowser.

```
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "WebKitBrowser, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
```

Now any help about how to make that library work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the platform target in the project properties to x86 instead of x64.

Comment: OK IT WORKS NOW THERE IS ANOTHER ERROR

`A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'c:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebbrowser\downloads\WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo\WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo\bin\WebKit.Interop.dll' because of an indirect reference to that assembly created by assembly 'c:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebbrowser\downloads\WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo\WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo\bin\WebKitBrowser.dll'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly. c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MY WEB KIT BROWSER\MY WEB KIT BROWSER\CSC`

Comment: did you try following the suggestion?  `Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly`

Comment: Well the assembly is for Embed Interop types so how can I change it to false.

Comment: Open the 'References' folder in your project, find the assembly and look at the Properties.  It should have an entry for `Embed Interop Types`